# MySQL string formatting + conditional statements

Tags: mysql, string, attributes, formatting, conditional-statements

I am selecting from an attribute table with the query below.. The problem is i require a formatted string based on a condition..

1.) String formatted starting with the string "Reply:"
2.) Follow the above string with: 
       Framed-Route + Framed-IP
       or Framed-IP is route is not set
       or Pool-Hint

Below is an example of what i require..

Example: Reply: Framed-IP="111.111.111.111"
Example2: Reply: PoolHint="8"

Can MySQL condition statements be used for this?

Edit addition

If (attribute_name == 'Framed-Route') Reply=Framed-Route="value";
elseif (attribute_name == 'Framed-IP') Reply=Framed-IP="value"
else Reply = PoolHint="value"

########### Output

```
SELECT attribute_name, value
  FROM user_product_attribute upa, product_attribute pa
 WHERE upa.user_product_id IN

   (  SELECT upa.user_product_id
        FROM user_product_attribute upa, user_product up, product_attribute pa, product p
       WHERE pa.attribute_name = 'username'
         AND pa.product_attribute_id = upa.product_attribute_id
         AND pa.product_id = p.product_id

         AND up.status = 'active'
         AND p.product_name = 'product1'
         AND upa.value = 'joebogs' )

   AND upa.product_attribute_id = pa.product_attribute_id
```

########### Output

attribute_name  value
Framed-Route    111.111.111.111
Framed-IP-Address   111.111.111.111
PoolHint    8
username    joeblogs
password    password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, you can use the MySQL `CONCAT()` function to do this:

Not using CONCAT:

```
mysql> SELECT attribute_name, value
    -> FROM user_product_attribute 
    -> WHERE attribute_name = 'Framed-IP-Address'\G

attribute_name: Framed-IP-Address
value: 111.111.111.111
```

Similar query using CONCAT function:

```
mysql> SELECT attribute_name, 
    -> CONCAT('Reply: Framed-IP=',value) AS 'formatted_value'
    -> FROM user_product_attribute
    -> WHERE attribute_name = 'Framed-IP-Address'\G

attribute_name: Framed-IP-Address
formatted_value: Reply: Framed-IP=111.111.111.111
```

CONCAT doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

As I said, not sure if that's what you needed though?

Lee- further to your comment, here's an updated query. This one uses CONCAT and IF:

```
mysql> SELECT attribute_name, 
    -> IF(attribute_name = 'Framed-Route', CONCAT('Reply=Framed-Route=',value),
    -> IF(attribute_name = 'Framed-IP', CONCAT('Reply=Framed-IP=',value), value))
    -> AS 'formatted_value'
    -> FROM user_product_attribute\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
 attribute_name: Framed-Route
formatted_value: Reply=Framed-Route=111.111.111.111

*************************** 2. row ***************************
 attribute_name: Framed-IP
formatted_value: Reply=Framed-IP=111.111.111.111
```

In the above, if the attribute_name is anything other than 'Framed-Route' or 'Framed-IP' the value is returned without any formatting.

Comment: Its a start... In addition however i need the following.. If (attribute_name == 'Framed-Route') Reply=Framed-Route="value"; elseif (attribute_name == 'Framed-IP') Reply=Framed-IP="value";

Comment: NP - It's updated. Please see the query at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, its in the right direction but not quite there.. I only need one value returned.. So if Framed IP exists, dont return poolhint.. Also if Framed-Route exists i need to conc Framed-IP and Framed-Route.. The current query returns a formatted string for each row.